# How to import sqlite open to another file as a module and then exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'd like to open a database (*.db) creating an other script designed for opening databases, import this file in the route script file as a module and exec.

(db/connection.js):

```
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import { open } from 'sqlite';

async function dataBase() {
      return open({
            filename: './db/test.db',
            driver: sqlite3.Database
            });
      };

export { dataBase };
```

(routes/example.js):

```
// database connection
import dataBase from './db/connection.js';
```

What am I supposed to do? If I try to do such thing like the following way, an error is being thrown:

```
dataBase.exec("SELECT * FROM test");
```